# Pycharm doesn't recognize nltk (installed with Anaconda)

Tags: python, pycharm, nltk, conda

I'm using PyCharm to write a program that uses the nltk package. My first line is:

```
 from nltk import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize
```

I have the nltk package imported in my 2.7 Python environment (the environment I'm working on) in PyCharm, as shown here:
[image: screenshot PyCharm not recognizing nltk package]

However, PyCharm doesn't recognize the `from nltk..` line. It's grayed out; it also shows this error:

`This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items.`

Here is my code:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize

annot1 = [(500L, u'[they seldom desire anything unless it belongs to     others]')]
annot2 = (500L, u'[they seldom desire anything unless it belongs to others]')

def scope_match(annot1, annot2):
    tokens1 = annot2[1].encode('utf-8')
    print type(tokens1)
    for string in tokens1:
        tokens2 = nltk.word_tokenize(string)
        print 'these are the tokens: ', tokens2
        new2 = [a.strip('[]').encode('utf-8') for a in tokens2]
        print new2

scope_agr = scope_match(annot1, annot2)
print scope_agr
```

When I run the code, I get this error:
    `C:\Users\nepal\Anaconda3\envs\py27\python.exe /Users/nepal/PycharmProjects/ScopeCue/ScopeComparison/scope-compare-inter-annotation-agreement-TEST.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/nepal/PycharmProjects/ScopeCue/ScopeComparison/scope-compare- inter-annotation-agreement-TEST.py", line 1, in <module>
from nltk import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize
ImportError: cannot import name word_tokenize

Process finished with exit code 1`
```

Can somebody guide me to solve this issue? Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: usually that error means there are variables that are conditionally defined so if the import statement is greyed out it seems PyCharm thinks it is a comment then giving you an error because `word_tokenize` isn't defined

Comment: is it possible there are odd non-printing characters in the file? Could you post the code here - then copy from SO back into PyCharm and see if it works then? (that works sometimes - gets rid of odd characters)

Comment: I added the code now. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: (please also include the full traceback) It works for me... well I got the error `nltk is undefined` because you import `word_tokenize` directly but then try to use `nltk.word_tokenize` but the import part worked.

Comment: I added the complete error code now. I am so sorry this seems so weird!

Comment: hmm, this is odd, it seems it is importing something, just not the correct module, try `import nltk ; print(nltk.__file__)` to see what file it is importing, if it is a file you made get it off of `sys.path` (delete it or move to another folder) or if it is the correct one (with the rest of python's library) then maybe try reinstalling nltk?

Comment: This is what I get: `C:\Users\nepal\Anaconda3\envs\py27\python.exe C:/Users/nepal/PycharmProjects/ScopeCue/ScopeComparison/problem.py
C:\Users\nepal\PycharmProjects\ScopeCue\ScopeComparison\nltk\__init__.pyc

Process finished with exit code 0`

Answer (score 2):

Your import error shows that the module `nltk` is found, but does not contain `word_tokenize`. 99% of the time this means that you have created a file `nltk.py` in the same directory as your script.

In fact you seem to be one of the exceptions-- sort of: The last error trace you posted in the comments shows that you have created an entire `nltk` package (a folder with `__init__.py`)! Get rid of it or rename it so that python can find the real `nltk`.

Comment: I had a file with `__init__.py` and I moved it. I have no files named `nltk.py`. Unfortunately, PyCharm still does not recognize the `from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize` (its grayed out and I get the same `This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't....` etc. Any idea what could be going on?..

Comment: You moved the folder `nltk`? Are you sure? Just forget pycharm. Get in an interactive python session, do a plain `import nltk`, and examine `nltk.__file__` like @Tadhg told you to do. (Or do that in a script if you don't know how to run an interactive session.)

Comment: this is what I get: `'C:\\Users\\nepal\\Anaconda3\\envs\\py27\\lib\\site-packages\\nltk\\__init__.pyc'` do you know what is wrong?....
(note about removing that `__init__.py` file: what I removed is a sub-folder that had that file)

Comment: Why use `pycharm` when you have  `atom` (https://atom.io/) or `sublime` (https://www.sublimetext.com/)? ;P

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by downloading the complete nltk package from  using `nltk.download()` from the terminal.

So, I opened a new python session and then did:

`import nltk`

`nltk.download()`

A new window opened and asked me if I wanted to download, which I accepted. Now it's running fine.

I wonder if Anaconda does not install the complete nltk package?.... Before trying this solution, I re-installed using Anaconda twice (`conda install -c anaconda nltk=3.2.1`). But it seems that using that command does not get the whole nltk package...

Anyways, I hope it helps the next person.

Comment: You are confused about the difference between "the nltk package" (Python code) and the nltk data, which you fetched with the downloader. Anaconda doesn't download that for you. Downloading the "book" bundle is almost certainly enough for anything you'll think of trying-- you don't need "all". But none of the imports fail because of missing data files. _Calling_ `sent_tokenize()` will give you an error without the necessary data, though.

Comment: If by data you refer to the actual text I want to tokenize, the answer is not. I am not using any data from nltk package. I'm using my own data, in the form of the two variables `annot1` and `annot2` shown in my code. Anyways, I'll ask my advisor about it. Thanks for going out of your way and get back to me.

Comment: That's not what I refer to, nltk data is not just corpora. Spend a few minutes on the nltk website if you still do not understand, or read the help on nltk.download.